# insert data from another function into another

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I feel like I am done with my project but i dont know to insert data from one function to another.
I tried calling the function first. but without the tkinter window appearing and the user "clicking" on the drop down menu the function does not have an argument.

I'll paste in my code and answer questions later :)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *


#read data
excel = 'new_export.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel, parse_dates=['Closed Date Time'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#Format / delete time from date column
data['Closed Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Closed Date Time'])
df['Close_Date'] = data['Closed Date Time'].dt.date
df['Close_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Close_Date'])
df['Year_Month'] = df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

#--------------------GUI ------------------

root = Tk()
root.title("Graph by Team")
root.geometry('400x200')

# --------------------FUNCTIONS---------------------------- #

#----------GRAPH--------------


def average(clicked):
    # check what team to look for
    choice = df.groupby(clicked)
   #choice = [tm for tm in df['Owned By Team'] if df['Owned By Team'] == clicked]
    # count number of tickets in month
    months = choice.groupby('Year_Month').size()
    # check if owner already exist in choice
    worked_on = set(df['Owned By'])
    count = len(worked_on)
    #calculate average
    calculate = months / count
    return calculate


def graph(average):
    x = average()
    plt.style.use("featherweight")
    # cant plot a function
    plt.hist(x)
    plt.title('Average by users ')
    plt.xlabel('Year & Month')
    # plt.ylabel('Average of tickets')
    plt.show()


# Drop Down Box
team = set(df['Owned By Team'])
clicked = StringVar()
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *team)
drop.pack()

newGraph = Button(root, text='Show graph', command=graph)
newGraph.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: to show what the data looks like]

## **EDIT**

Sooo... I went step by step through the code and found one significant problem at the moment.

I have 'choice' , 'month' and 'worked_on'

'choice' --> this works. it filters from the excel all lines that have eg. "IT Service Desk" written.

'month' --> this shows tickets done per month within choice.

'worked_on' --> now this is the problem. I need to count each month how many users were working on the tickets that where filtered out by the keyword eg. "IT Service Desk"
he needs to be able to differentiate what month it was and then count the average for each month in the last step.

Any idea ???

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring df and your gui elements outside of the scope of the functions, you don't even need to pass arguments. (Note: it would be more correct to create a class for the whole though)

```
# beginning of your code... 

#--------------------GUI ------------------

root = Tk()
root.title("Graph by Team")
root.geometry('400x200')

team = set(df['Owned By Team'])
clicked = StringVar()
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *team)
drop.pack()

# --------------------FUNCTIONS---------------------------- #

#----------GRAPH--------------


def average():
    # check what team to look for
    choice = df.groupby(clicked.get())
   #choice = [tm for tm in df['Owned By Team'] if df['Owned By Team'] == clicked]
    # count number of tickets in month
    months = choice.groupby('Year_Month').size()
    # check if owner already exist in choice
    worked_on = set(df['Owned By'])
    count = len(worked_on)
    #calculate average
    calculate = months / count
    return calculate


def graph():
    x = average()
    plt.style.use("featherweight")
    # cant plot a function
    plt.hist(x)
    plt.title('Average by users ')
    plt.xlabel('Year & Month')
    # plt.ylabel('Average of tickets')
    plt.show()

newGraph = Button(root, text='Show graph', command=graph)
newGraph.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried to create a class but then Pycharm tells me its would be better to leave it as a method so i changed it back.

Comment: Unfortunatelly :( I am getting a KeyError

Comment: You didn't provide a df so it's hard to debug. But `choice = df.groupby(clicked.get())` doesn't seem to make sense (you group by a column, not its values). Try replacing with `choice = df[df['Owned By Team']==clicked.get()]`